# git log mismatch in different machines

Tags: git

I have created a branch from `master`, `offsore-dev`. In one machine1 git log says:

```
$ git log --branches
commit ac7bbc5e9b07d381309edc885d7285820a05b199
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 10:12:12 2014 +0000

    Second Commit in offsore-dev branch

commit 7c909e2d30545fab7a27e29163ae98ac6b1f6947
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 09:56:19 2014 +0000

    Offsore-dev-commit1

commit 7cc48e58d7d16dc6e761628ceabf8fdc9c4fc378
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 09:29:39 2014 +0000

    my second commit

commit f2e1e6e3115c6d0ae0b057836e1c91779328fabe
Author: Papu <papubhat@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 17:18:55 2014 +0530

    My first Commit

Administrator@PAPU-SERVER /cygdrive/E/testgit/testgit
```

In another machine2

```
commit 7c909e2d30545fab7a27e29163ae98ac6b1f6947
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 09:56:19 2014 +0000

    Offsore-dev-commit1

commit 7cc48e58d7d16dc6e761628ceabf8fdc9c4fc378
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 09:29:39 2014 +0000

    my second commit

commit f2e1e6e3115c6d0ae0b057836e1c91779328fabe
Author: Papu <papubhat@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 17:18:55 2014 +0530

    My first Commit
```

I have pushed repeatedly from machine1 and pulled all from machine2. Why do the logs still show a difference? On the second machine why am I missing the "Second Commit in offsore-dev branch" commit?

### Edit

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://192.168.1.19:/opt/data/git/testgit.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://192.168.1.19:/opt/data/git/testgit.git (push

$ git log offsore-dev..
commit 8e9496d2f0c8a933a98b78e6050301d1fb199006
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Sat Mar 8 06:46:15 2014 +0000

    Third commit

commit ac7bbc5e9b07d381309edc885d7285820a05b199
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 10:12:12 2014 +0000

    Second Commit in offsore-dev branch

$ git push -u origin offsore-dev
Branch offsore-dev set up to track remote branch offsore-dev from origin.
Everything up-to-date

$ git log offsore-dev..
commit 8e9496d2f0c8a933a98b78e6050301d1fb199006
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Sat Mar 8 06:46:15 2014 +0000

    Third commit

commit ac7bbc5e9b07d381309edc885d7285820a05b199
Author: U-PAPU-SERVER\Administrator <Administrator@PAPU-SERVER.(none)>
Date:   Fri Mar 7 10:12:12 2014 +0000

enter code here
    Second Commit in offsore-dev branch
```

I think its never pushed from this machine. Not sure about the reason.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if the remote does not have a branch named `offshore-dev`. To override this behavior you can specify the branch name explicitly in the command

```
git push origin offshore-dev:<remote name>
```

If you want to update `master` then run the following:

```
git push origin offshore-dev:master
```

After this when you run

```
git pull
```

or

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

on machine2 you should see the change.